# Logic to check current session if it has future session then disable button

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-api, laravel-models

Hello i have parent table and child table sessions. Which i use to create student schedule.

```
terms
-----
id
name
start_date
end_date
term_type
active
```

```
sessions
--------
id
term_id
start_date
end_date
session_type
```

Here's the relationship

```
public function term()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Term', 'term_id');
}
```

```
public function sessions()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Session', 'term_id', 'id');
}
```

In my Session Model i have this attribute to delete a session record.

When future session is present terms page. Inner session page should not be allowed to be deleted.

Example:
Current session is august-september

future session should be october-december.

This logic seems to be tricky for me, i have tried to compare both `end_date` and `start_date` i realize its not going to work because it just compare itself. Honestly im not sure what im doing anymore.

```
public function getAllowDeleteAttribute()
{
  if($this->term()->where('end_date') > $this->term()->where('start_date')){
    return !($this->schedules()->exists() || $this->sessionFees()->exists());
  }
}
```

The result is current session cannot be deleted. All i want is to restrict any user to delete future sessions not the current.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly it should be somenthing like this:

```
public function getAllowDeleteAttribute()
{
    if($this->term()->whereDate('start_date', '<=', today())->count()){
        return !($this->schedules()->exists() || $this->sessionFees()->exists());
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to pre-load your relationship in controller for better performance:

```
$sessions = Session::with('terms')->get();
```